Python pandas read_excel fills blank cells with 0
I am at a complete loss over this. I'm reading in a horrible Excel file with pandas using the following line:
pd_df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet, header=10, skipfooter=7, dtype='string', na_filter=False)

For one sheet, pandas apparently replaces/fills all empty cells with 0 - where "empty" means either really empty or containing two spaces. For another sheet, where blank cells are filled with at least five spaces, no replacement happens. Does anyone have any experience with that? It seems so random that this happens with exactly the same code.

I was going to ask why you've got na_filter=False in there and do you still have problems if you take it out

@EmiOB At one point in my experimenting with this, removing the na_filter option lead to me having only NA values. Apparently this is not the case any more, I only get the empty row between header and data as NAs, the rest is fine (with 0s still).

I had similar cases and it mainly came from :

Data types on several cells. For some reason Excel sometimes attributes types to cells, like number or percentages while it should basically be nothing. Try to manually set all your cells to the same type.
Blank spaces within empty cells, that can be easily fixed using .strip() method from Python.

Hope it will help

I thought setting dtype='string' was setting all my cells to the same type? Is there something else I could try? And how do I strip blank spaces when they have already been replaced by 0 upon reading the data in?

I was thinking about modifying first in Excel, just to see if it solves the problem. Copy paste your data (as values, not using only ctrl+c/v) and paste them in another Excel and try with this one.
Additionnally, select everything and set it to a default format, and see what happens.

I see, thank you for the clarification! And... that actually worked. The empty cells are actually cells with 0 in them! I have no idea how that works, as the same cells are empty when converting to CSV, but here we are.
